# error: cannot find symbol BuildConfig.DEBUG

Tags: android, reactjs, expo, react-native

i have ejected from expo managed project to bare workflow project. but when i try to run the project it shoes error that

```
E:\Mnor Project 1\ejected\android\app\src\main\java\com\minorproject\MainApplication.java:40: error: cannot find symbol
      return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
```

Here is my imports in MainAplication.java

```
package com.minorproject;

import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;

import com.facebook.react.PackageList;
import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication;
import com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager;
import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost;
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.shell.MainReactPackage;
import com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader;
import com.minorproject.generated.BasePackageList;

import org.unimodules.adapters.react.ReactAdapterPackage;
import org.unimodules.adapters.react.ModuleRegistryAdapter;
import org.unimodules.adapters.react.ReactModuleRegistryProvider;
import org.unimodules.core.interfaces.Package;
import org.unimodules.core.interfaces.SingletonModule;
import expo.modules.constants.ConstantsPackage;
import expo.modules.permissions.PermissionsPackage;
import expo.modules.filesystem.FileSystemPackage;
import expo.modules.updates.UpdatesController;
```

and here is my inports in MainActivity.java

```
package com.minorproject;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.facebook.react.ReactActivity;
import com.facebook.react.ReactActivityDelegate;
import com.facebook.react.ReactRootView;
import com.swmansion.gesturehandler.react.RNGestureHandlerEnabledRootView;

import expo.modules.splashscreen.SplashScreen;
import expo.modules.splashscreen.SplashScreenImageResizeMode;
```

Here is my package.json

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "minor-project",
    "slug": "minor-project",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": ["**/*"],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "bundleIdentifier": "com.akshay2739.minorproject"
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    },
    "sdkVersion": "38.0.0",
    "platforms": ["ios", "android", "web"],
    "android": {
      "package": "com.akshay2739.minorproject"
    }
  }
}
```

I have tried to import `import com.facebook.react.BuildConfig;` but then it builds but crashes as i run the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I searched it on opened issues on expo repo. and i found this open issue.

https://github.com/expo/expo-cli/issues/2711

Answer (score 7):

Replace the line `import expo.modules.splashscreen.SplashScreen;`
with `import expo.modules.splashscreen.singletons.SplashScreen;` in the MainActivity.java file of your android folder.

Comment: Close the Metro server window and run `yarn android` again.

Comment: After wasting a couple of hours your answer finally solved my problem. I really don't know why expo crew work so hard to confuse everyone. Every update is a whole new mess. OMG. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> Breaking changes On Android scoped SplashScreen objects into separate singletons sub-package. (#10294 by @bbarthec) Updated
> @expo/configure-splash-screen to v0.2.0.

so downgrade easy:

```
npm uninstall -g @expo/configure-splash-screen && npm install -g @expo/configure-splash-screen@0.2.0
```

Comment: from the project root directory:

rm -rf node_modules && npm uninstall -g @expo/configure-splash-screen && npm install -g @expo/configure-splash-screen@0.2.0 && n[m install